# Getting the datetime format from the different datetime values

Tags: javascript, java, html, time, java-time

I have a program where the user uploads a CSV file which contains multiple columns. The first column is the time which could be in any one of the following formats.

```
Format ------ example

ofLocalizedDate(dateStyle) -----   '2011-12-03'  
ofLocalizedTime(timeStyle) -----   '10:15:30'  
ofLocalizedDateTime(dateTimeStyle)  ------ '3 Jun 2008 11:05:30'  
ofLocalizedDateTime(dateStyle,timeStyle) ----- '3 Jun 2008 11:05'  
BASIC_ISO_DATE  ------ '20111203'  
ISO_LOCAL_DATE  ------ '2011-12-03'  
ISO_OFFSET_DATE ------  '2011-12-03+01:00'  
ISO_DATE   ------ '2011-12-03+01:00'; '2011-12-03'  
ISO_LOCAL_TIME  ------ '10:15:30'  
ISO_OFFSET_TIME ------  '10:15:30+01:00'  
ISO_TIME  ------ '10:15:30+01:00'; '10:15:30'  
ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME ------ '2011-12-03T10:15:30'  
ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME   ------   2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00  
ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME ------ '2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]'  
ISO_DATE_TIME  ------ '2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]'  
ISO_ORDINAL_DATE  ------- '2012-337'  
ISO_WEEK_DATE  ------   2012-W48-6  
ISO_INSTANT  ------  '2011-12-03T10:15:30Z'  
RFC_1123_DATE_TIME  ------ 'Tue, 3 Jun 2008 11:05:30 GMT'  
Unix seconds -----       1528972575  
Unix Milliseconds -----  1491979683469  
Unix Microseconds    
MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss  
YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss
```

I want to write a program in JavaScript which runs on the browser so that I first read the CSV and then display time format from the file.
The reading on the file is done.
But I am not getting how could I check between all these times and the time inn the file.
Any help is appreciated!
Thank You!

Comment: If the localized ones can be in any locale, it’s not possible. If you know the locale it may be viable to try all the possible formats in turn and see which one works. You will also need to know the time zone or offset, since not all formats include this information. Finally you will need to know a reasonable range of datetimes to distinguish Unix seconds, milliseconds and microseconds.

Comment: Why would you accept such arbitrary values as inputs? That makes no sense. It is impossible to generically parse such a range of possible formats. The localized values could use any locale. The range of inputs you list are not even the same kind of meaning. The "Local…" types are not attached to the timeline and do *not* represent a moment, a completely different animal than the ones with an offset or zone. A date-only, a time-of-day, and a date-with-time-of-day are three different kinds of things. Your Question seems preposterous to me. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

well once you have the value now you need to show the time.
I think you need to compare your value to each one.
as there is only around 25 time formats its like constant time.

```
for (i = 0; i < timeFormat.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0;j < timeFormat [i] [j] ; j++) {
    // compare here each format to your value
    // it is tough to write a function but i guess you need to do 
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah! That is what I had thought but it would be a big function and a lot of constraints.

Comment: because you need to show which type of timezone it is then i guess you need to write such function. I will see if there is some more easy solution